# Upper bounds on the length of the shortest vector in lattices associated to polynomial congruences

Tags: nt.number-theory, lattices

We consider a lattice $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{Z}^2$, and put $\lambda_1(\Lambda), \lambda_2(\Lambda)$ for successive minima of the lattice $\Lambda$.

By a well-known theorem of Minkowski, one has that

$$\displaystyle \lambda_1(\Lambda) \leq 2(\det(\Lambda)/\pi)^{1/2}.$$

For me it is quite annoying that the constant on the right hand side is greater than one, so I am wondering if it is possible to obtain an upper bound with a constant that is less than one, at least in some special cases.

One particular case where this is possible is the following. Consider the congruence

$$\displaystyle x^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{d}.$$

The solutions to this congruence lie on a finite union of lattices, defined by

$$\displaystyle u \equiv \omega v \pmod{d}$$

for some $\omega \in \mathbb{Z}$. Note that $\det(\Lambda_\omega) = d$. For such a lattice $\Lambda_\omega$, we must have $\lambda_1(\Lambda_\omega) \leq d$, since in each such lattice it is possible to find a vector $(r,s)$ such that $r^2 + s^2 = d$.

Is it possible to improve the bound provided by Minkowski's theorem for $\lambda_1(\Lambda)$ for general $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{Z}^2$? What about lattices that arise from polynomial congruences in general?

Comment: You're asking in effect for the Hermite constant for lattices in the plane.
It's well known (and I'm sure you know it well but momentarily forgot)
that the largest possible constant occurs for a triangular lattice.
If we scale this lattice to have $\lambda_1 = 1$ then the determinant is
$\sqrt{3}/2$, so the best we can do is $\lambda_1 \leq (4/3)^{1/4} \Delta^{1/2}$
where the constant is still a bit above $1$.  For a square lattice such as
you get from $x^2+1 \equiv 0$, the constant is exactly $1$.  I don't know
where the factor $1/\sqrt2$ comes from.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies yes I made a mistake in the question; I will fix the error

Comment: Well $x^2+x+1 \equiv 0$ always gives a triangular lattice.